# Why $cG = 0.02 \rm N$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

The unit of their product is **Newton** and its value is precisely ([up to their uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_constant#Table_of_physical_constants)) equal to 1/50.

And I know! It is tempting to re-think that they might not be constant, but their product must. Especially since the unit of their product is **entered** by Sir Isaac, thus fairly named by him "Newton", and it was not there beforehand.

There are several studies trying to reinterpret the physical phenomena by a variable speed of light ([like this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06763)) and it is being more fashionable todays.

Of course, it could be just due to an accident but considering the low order of commensurability of 1/50 and its unit, I think it is  worthwhile to ask:

**Any idea why the product of these two constants is so rational? and how can we interpret their unit physically?**

---

The question is wrong! Thanks to David, the unit was wrong.
Sorry community.

Comment: Yet another numerological question.

Comment: Very interesting fact! Nevertheless, in imperial units the value is $1.863\cdot 10^5\text{mi}\,\text{G} / s$. The value 1/50 is based on the definitions of the meter, second and kilogram, which are completely arbitrary with respect to fundamental physics. Only unitless constants, like the fine structure constant, could have any meaning to their numerical value.

Comment: The units aren't correct. The product of the speed of light and the universal gravitational constant has units of $\text{length}^4/(\text{mass} * \text{time}^3)$. A newton has units of $\text{length} * \text{mass}/\text{time}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be clear, $cG$ is a dimensionful quantity, and so it can take any numerical value given an appropriate unit system. Its value is SI units depends on our definition of the meter and second and kilogram; those are all based on historical, human factors, and are not going to be part of a deep physical explanation.

Still, let's think about it statistically. Would we expect this kind of result to happen "by chance" if there were no deep explanation?

Plugging in numbers on wolfram alpha, I find, $cG=0.02001\ {\rm m^4\ kg^{-1}\ s^{-3}}$. (Note this is not a unit of force, which is ${\rm m\ kg\ s^{-2}}$). So what you basically want to explain is what the odds are of having $2$ zeros after the first significant digit. Since there were $10$ options for the first digit and $10$ options for the second digit, the odds of this happening by chance are $1$ in $100$. (It's actually slightly smaller since we really want the odds of the first digit being non-zero and the next two being zero, so the odds are really $0.009$ instead of $0.01$, but we can ignore that to keep the numbers simple).

Let's restrict the list of fundamental constants to just $c, G,$ and $\hbar$. I suspect that you would have been just as surprised if it had turned out $c/G$ had been "this close to rational." So let's say we want to look over all expressions of the form
\begin{equation}
x = c^m G^n \hbar^k
\end{equation}
where $m$, $n$, $k$ each take a value in the set $\{-1, 0, 1\}$. Since there are $3$ choices for $m$, $3$ choices for $n$, and $3$ choices for $k$, there are $27$ different values of $x$.

For arbitrary units, I think it's reasonable to assume the digits will be essentially random. That's not quite true, since of course $m=n=k=0$ will give $x=1$, so let's remove that possibility.

So we have $26$ random numbers. The odds of *some* combination of constants producing a number with the two subleading digits being $0$ is then about $26\%$, or about one in four. On the one hand, that's less likely to happen than not, but on the other hand I wouldn't bet my house against it happening. In most sciences, the threshold for considering a result statistically significant is if random chance (strictly speaking the "null hypothesis") would only produce an outcome at least as extreme as the one you observe $5\%$ of the time; in physics the threshold is much more stringent, about 1 in a million. So, this result is very much consistent with what you would expect from random chance, under very mild assumptions of what combinations of constants you would find interesting.

You could quibble with a lot of details of the calculation. For example, there are other constants you could consider, and maybe you wouldn't be surprised if $c^2G$ was close to rational, so we should include $2$ in the set of possible powers as well. And fair enough, this is really just meant as an illustrative exercise, not a truly rigorous estimate of the odds. But those effects would tend to make the chance of such a thing happening by chance even larger.

The overall point is that numerical coincidences are much easier to produce by pure chance than you might think, and this one is not particularly surprising.

Comment: I think you should address the OP’s misconception that $cG$ is a force.

Comment: @Ghoster I added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, since those values aren’t exact, their product isn’t either. This removes most of the value of this remark.

Second, the product isn’t unitless, so it’s arbitrary and depends on the chosen system of units.

So it’s doubtful that this value has any meaning.